# How to quickly insert huge datas into datastore while running on GAE development server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

### Background:

While coding on GAE's local Development Web Server, user need to upload Mega-level datas and store (not straight forward store, but need many format check and translate) them into Datastore using **deferred library**.

Usually about 50,000 entities, CSV File size is about 5MB, and I tried to insert 200 entities each time using deferred library.

And I used python.

### Problem

The development server is really slow that I need to wait **one/more hours** to finish this upload process.

I used --use_sqlite option to speed up the development web server.

### Question:

Is there any other method or tuning that can make it faster?

Comment: Why are you trying to load this much data into the development server? It's really not built for it.

Comment: This is the must-have data for testing the codes that i extracted from much larger Giga level data-sets. Seems I should change to another way to test the codes.

Comment: And this is just **50k** entities, any database (like MySql, Mongo) can handle this easily... even simulate Bigtable using sqlite, it should not such slow, right?

Comment: 50k entries isn't a lot for any real database, no - but the one in the dev_appserver was built with compatibility, not performance, in mind. Are you sure you can't do this with a smaller dataset?

Comment: to @NickJohnson , thank you for your information, this part of code have almost finished, next time I will use smaller dataset definitely. It a pain to reduce the size of the dataset in some case, especially in computational work that I need to add many extra codes instead of just delete some rows in the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) is definitely an option for loading CSV files. Use [blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html) to upload CSV file and then setup `BlobstoreLineInputReader` mapper type to load data into datastore.

Some more links: Python Guide to mapreduce reader types is [here](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/UserGuidePython#Specifying_readers). The one of interest is *BlobstoreLineInputReader*. The only input it requires is the key to the blobstore record containing uploaded CSV file.

Comment: Although not directly answered the question, but provided a option for later optimize. Thank you very much.